What's the difference between "On" and "On + Boost" in the "NVIDIA REFLECT LOW LATENCY" Display setting within Hogwarts Legacy?
I'm busy tweaking settings in Hogwarts Legacy to try and get my game to perform better and crash less.
I found a setting called "NVIDIA REFLECT LOW LATENCY" and it has two options, "On" and "On + Boost".

What's the difference between "On" and "On + Boost"?
I've changed it between both of them, but I don't see or feel a difference. What does it do and what's the difference?

I also checked the latency min / max when turning it off, on or even on + boost. There was no latency change nor FPS change. Tested each one for 30 seconds and I could not see a change on the 4090. For all cases the latency was 12ms - 22ms (~2 for each).
